# Flask_admin @expose('/', methods=('GET', 'POST')) Почему не работает метод POST?

Tags: python, flask, flask-admin

Flask_admin **@expose**('/', methods=('GET',)) ":param methods: Allowed HTTP methods. By default only GET is allowed." Как использовать отправку данных **POST** с декоратором @expose?

```
class InvoicesView(BaseView):
@expose('/', methods=('GET', 'POST')) # POST вызывает ошибку Method Not Allowed
def inv_page(self):
    form = Price()
    if request.method == "POST":
        print('ок, работает')
    else:
        return self.render('admin/custom_invoices.html', form=form)
```

Comment: Такое впечатление что вы дергаете не эту вьюху. POST вы верно определили.

Comment: Да? Опишите ваше понимание проблемы пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

Забыл в форме указать путь к обработчику

```
<form method="POST" action="/admin/inv/">
```

Также добавил route и всё заработало

```
 @app.route('/admin/inv/', methods=['POST'])
    def form_price():
        if request.method == "POST":
            if current_user.is_authenticated:    
                if request.form.get('rub'):
```